# Simple toggle animation won't work

Tags: beamer, animate, tikz-pic, ifthenelse

I tried a simple toggleanimation.

First i create a bool value
If I set it to true, the if path is performed, set it to false results in the else path.
So far so good.
Within an animateinline i want to draw something based on the boolean expression.
With the if path i set the variable to false, so I would expect, that in the next loop the false path is used and the other way around for the else path (simple lock logic).

What do i have to change to get the expected result (toggling of the different draws each frame).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, positioning}

\newboolean{boolvar} %declaration, seems to be false by default
\setboolean{boolvar}{true}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{animateinline}[controls,loop]{50}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \ifthenelse{\boolean{boolvar}}
                    %if:
                    { 
                        \node[draw=green,
                        minimum width=2cm,
                        minimum height=1cm] at (0,1) {1};
                        \setboolean{boolvar}{false} %this should set boolvar to false
                    } 
                    %else:
                    {   
                        \node[draw=red,
                        minimum width=2cm,
                        minimum height=1cm] at (0,1) {0};
                        \setboolean{boolvar}{true} %this should set boolvar to true
                    } 
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{animateinline}
    \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is none of `\newframe` nor `\multiframe` commands to be found in the `animateinline` environment. Therefore, only one animation frame is produced based on the initial setting of the boolean variable.

One could place `\multiframe{2}{}{...}` around the `tikzpicture` environment to get two animation frames. Note however, that variables defined or set within the body of `\multiframe` have local scope that is limited to the current loop execution. Pkg `ifthen` does not allow global setting of boolean variables. Alternatively, package `etoolbox` can be used which allows commands for setting booleans to be prefixed with `\global`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, positioning}

\newbool{boolvar} %declaration, seems to be false by default
\booltrue{boolvar}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{animateinline}[controls,loop]{50}
        \multiframe{2}{}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \ifbool{boolvar}
                    %if:
                    { 
                        \node[draw=green,
                        minimum width=2cm,
                        minimum height=1cm] at (0,1) {1};
                        \global\boolfalse{boolvar} %this should set boolvar to false
                    } 
                    %else:
                    {   
                        \node[draw=red,
                        minimum width=2cm,
                        minimum height=1cm] at (0,1) {0};
                        \global\booltrue{boolvar} %this should set boolvar to true
                    } 
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }    
        \end{animateinline}
    \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

But, for the problem at hand it might be easier to just use a `\newframe` in order to produce two animation frames:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, positioning}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{animateinline}[controls,loop]{50}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw=green,
        minimum width=2cm,
        minimum height=1cm] at (0,1) {1};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \newframe
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw=red,
        minimum width=2cm,
        minimum height=1cm] at (0,1) {0};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{animateinline}
  \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: That helps. The problem with irregular Latex users is, that finding simple solution is often not that easy.

Comment: You're welcome. This is what this site is made for.